# Most efficient way to search by date in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

In a SQL Server database, I have a table with a `DateTime` column and I want to get rows for a specific date.

I have found many options, like:

1. `WHERE myColumn BETWEEN '2020-10-10T00:00:00.00' AND '2020-10-10T23:59:59.999'`
2. `WHERE CAST(myColumn AS date) = '2020-10-10'`
3. `WHERE date LIKE '%2020-10-10%'`

...

Which one of them is the fastest?

Comment: Run some performance tests and see for yourself ! I'd also suggest #4: `WHERE myColumn >= '2020-10-10' AND myColumn < '2020-10-11'`

Comment: #1 is wrong because .999 will be converted to 1 second and push your selection into next day. you need .997.  #2. blows out indexes because you cast the "left side". #3 just sucks because you aren't guaranteed that date converted to string contains iso date. @marc_s suggestion is good too

Comment: Also - if you're not interested in the time portion - why don't you just use `DATE` as your column's datatype ?? That would make life so much easier ....

Comment: I agree with @marc_s.  Also, a must read: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: And [which is fastest](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) is a test that takes less time than creating a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Aside: You might want to read up on [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to have a better understanding of what is going on when you compare a `Date` or `DateTime` to a string. Note that your `like` comparison needs an explicit conversion to specify the format: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UVcAZV9a).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by @marc_s: None of these options are correct.

- `WHERE myColumn BETWEEN '2020-10-10T00:00:00.00' AND '2020-10-10T23:59:59.999'`
  This option does not correctly handle the end point. For `datetime` values you will get a rounding error that will include the begnning of the next day, and for `datetime2` you will miss 1 millisecond.
- `WHERE CAST(myColumn AS date) = '2020-10-10'`
  This option, while there is some handling in the compiler for it, partially prevents indexes being used properly. The cardinality estimation will almost certainly be off.
- `WHERE date LIKE '%2020-10-10%'`
  This is the worst: it converts the date to a string, completely preventing usage of indexes.

**What you actually need is:**

```sql
WHERE myColumn >= '2020-10-10' AND myColumn < '2020-10-11'
```

This covers a date *range* and allows an index seek over that range. See also [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

You obviously still need an index on the date column, but as we can't see the rest of your query or your table definition we can't help with that.

Comment: Do you think it would be worth mentioning the concept of a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expresssion?