# How to efficiently get records matching a date in a DateTime column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I have a LogNet table with I don't even know how many rows. Possibly approaching a million or even more. Each record has a DateTime for when the record was created. When I need records for a specific date I run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM AppLog WHERE CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) = CONVERT(DATE,'04/05/2023')
```

Essentially I convert the column value to a Date to remove the time, and convert a varchar to a Date to match it on. This maxes out our server and therefore I can only run it in the middle of the night. I am planning to add an index to [Date] to see if that helps.

I know CONVERT is not terribly efficient, so what is the best way to do this? If it matters I do know the time range of the records I need.

Comment: Use a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expression, such as `WHERE [Date] >= '2023-05-04' AND [Date] < '2023-05-05'`.

Comment: I expect this is a duplicate question, but *I* can't find a suitable duplicate.

Comment: That is a much faster query thank you

Comment: If it has worked, I'll make my comment into an answer for you :) and someone else can indicate if the question is a duplicate if they can find one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to search by date in SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76161831/most-efficient-way-to-search-by-date-in-sql-server-database). It's an oldie but goodie from yesterday.

Comment: @HABO A good find, and I agree; however, that question has two close votes on it at the moment!

Comment: @AndrewMorton - The `CONVERT(DATE` is [somewhat sargable though not ideally so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/3690) - though as there is no index on this column no index seek will be possible either way

Comment: "approaching a million" is pretty small TBH - What do you mean by "maxes out our server"? w.r.t. what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expression, such as

```
WHERE [Date] >= '2023-05-04' AND [Date] < '2023-05-05'
```

If a date literal doesn't have a time part, the time part is zero, so the `>=` comparison will start from the very first part of 2023-05-04 (in this example), and the `<` comparison will look for the latest entry that is not in 2023-05-05 (or later, of course).

Comment: @Joe Just out of interest, how much did it improve the query performance?